# How update ACF field in savepost hook and wp remote post

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

How I can update post meta or ACF fields by wp_remote_post or other method by using exists API ?

```
function publish_content($post_id, $post, $update)
{

    // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
    if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
        return;
    }


    $full_content = get_field('full_content', $post_id);

    $login = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    $response = wp_remote_post(
        'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/12',
        array(
            'headers' => array(
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode("$login:$password")
            )
        )
    );

    //I need Update ACF Field Value in example.com site

}

add_action('save_post', 'publish_content', 11, 3);
```

I don't want to develop new API on the destination site and I want to use the existing (wp/v2/posts/{id}) WordPress API.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $api_response = wp_remote_post( 'yourwebiste.com/wp- 
    json/wp/v2/posts/893', 
    array(    
   'headers' => array('Authorization' => 'Basic ' .  base64_encode( 
    "$login:$password" )),
    'body' => array(

        'acffieldname' => '2150',
    ),

));
```

Above the "d_amount" is the acf field, now you just need to paste the following code in function.php or plugin file:

```
    function register_related_posts_api_field()
    {
        register_rest_field('posttype', 'd_amount',
            array(
                'get_callback' => function($post){ return get_field('d_amount', 
                    $post['id']);}
                'update_callback' => function ($value, $object, $fieldName) 
                  {
                  return update_field("d_amount",$value,$object->ID);},
                'schema' => null,
                     )     
                   );
         
     }


    add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_related_posts_api_field');
```

note: above the 'd_amount' is acf field name
The above code will create you a rest api field which would be called and updated on the same wp api